# I'm experiencing network issues while attempting to connect to a Firebase database in my React project.(ubuntu)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ubuntu, npm, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect the **Firebase database** in my react project but **network error** occurs, My internet is working fine but still it gives error, I am using **ubuntu** OS.

I try this cmd in terminal,

**npm install firebase@10.4.0 --save**,
and this error occurs :

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@firebase%2fstorage: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-21T08_57_09_202Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.